# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 has not been Registered" Error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting a "The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 has not been registered" error.  I have the data objects library downloaded and I have "Microsoft Office 12.0 Access database engine Object Library" selected.

I'm running the Windows Vista 32-bit operating system.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to relate to using an XLS file in 2007.

Here are a couple of possible solutions:

[MSDN Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/20aafd3d-0219-4706-abb4-e4b35aebb18e/)